# jquery parseXML throwing invalid XML error

Tags: jquery, xml

Here is the error that is being thrown:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><mobile-data-series xmlns="http://www.seecontrol.com/nexus/XMLSchema" index="0" total="5"><data-set key="$1021.3039604"><mobile-value code="_rc$258330_value"><valueText>DMG DMU 160P</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258331_value"><valueText>32</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258332_value"><valueText>Aborted</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258333_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258334_value"><valueText>DMG_DMU_160P</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258335_value"><valueText>'OST'</valueText></mobile-value></data-set><data-set key="$1021.3039607"><mobile-value code="_rc$258330_value"><valueText>Hermle C50U</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258331_value"><valueText>35</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258332_value"><valueText>Aborted</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258333_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258334_value"><valueText>HERMLE_C50U</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258335_value"><valueText>'OSTORE1_SYFFMPFW3.MPF'</valueText></mobile-value></data-set><data-set key="$1021.3039926"><mobile-value code="_rc$258330_value"><valueText>Huron KX200</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258331_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258332_value"><valueText>Interrupted</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258333_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258334_value"><valueText>HURON_KX200</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258335_value"><valueText></valueText></mobile-value></data-set><data-set key="$1021.3042653"><mobile-value code="_rc$258330_value"><valueText>Huron VX12</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258331_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258332_value"><valueText>In Progress</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258333_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258334_value"><valueText>HURON_VX12</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258335_value"><valueText>DEMO_Huron_VX12</valueText></mobile-value></data-set><data-set key="$1021.3039802"><mobile-value code="_rc$258330_value"><valueText>Virtual Machine Tool</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258331_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258332_value"><valueText>Interrupted</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258333_value"><valueText>0</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258334_value"><valueText>VirtualMachineTool</valueText></mobile-value><mobile-value code="_rc$258335_value"><valueText></valueText></mobile-value></data-set></mobile-data-series>
    at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.r.parseXML (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Object.complete (app.js:26)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Here is the formatted xml for ref:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mobile-data-series
    xmlns="http://www.seecontrol.com/nexus/XMLSchema" index="0" total="5">
    <data-set key="$1021.3039604">
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259230_value">
            <valueText>DMG DMU 160P</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259231_value">
            <valueText>32</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259232_value">
            <valueText>Aborted</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259233_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259234_value">
            <valueText>DMG_DMU_160P</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259235_value">
            <valueText>"OST"</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
    </data-set>
    <data-set key="$1021.3039607">
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259230_value">
            <valueText>Hermle C50U</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259231_value">
            <valueText>35</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259232_value">
            <valueText>Aborted</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259233_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259234_value">
            <valueText>HERMLE_C50U</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259235_value">
            <valueText>"OSTORE1_SYFFMPFW3.MPF"</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
    </data-set>
    <data-set key="$1021.3039926">
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259230_value">
            <valueText>Huron KX200</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259231_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259232_value">
            <valueText>Interrupted</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259233_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259234_value">
            <valueText>HURON_KX200</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259235_value">
            <valueText></valueText>
        </mobile-value>
    </data-set>
    <data-set key="$1021.3042653">
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259230_value">
            <valueText>Huron VX12</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259231_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259232_value">
            <valueText>In Progress</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259233_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259234_value">
            <valueText>HURON_VX12</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259235_value">
            <valueText>DEMO_Huron_VX12</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
    </data-set>
    <data-set key="$1021.3039802">
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259230_value">
            <valueText>Virtual Machine Tool</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259231_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259232_value">
            <valueText>Interrupted</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259233_value">
            <valueText>0</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259234_value">
            <valueText>VirtualMachineTool</valueText>
        </mobile-value>
        <mobile-value code="_rc$259235_value">
            <valueText></valueText>
        </mobile-value>
    </data-set>
</mobile-data-series>
```

I am clueless!

Answer (score 1):

You should display the code that comes before your formatted xml. But most times like yours, you already have your data in XML format and doesn't need parsing. 
jQuery.parseXML() Parses a string into an XML document but you trying to parse an XML into an XML
Thats because your data is already in XML format and doesn't need parsing. Just continue with the next line of code...
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$title = $xml.find( "count" ); //or whatever your next line is
No need to parseXML
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your `xml` have single quotes in value like `'OST'` and `'OSTORE1_SYFFMPFW3.MPF'` use `&#39;` instead `'` in `xml` string then this will work.

```
var xml = 'Your xml string';
var  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
console.log(xmlDoc)
```

[Working example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/o280wfmn/)

Comment: please check. I have put the fixed xml. but i see the same issue